# RXJS: observableCreate is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, observable, rxjs

I'm trying to detect when an element gets added to the dom, like so:

```
import {DOM} from 'rx-dom'; 
let mutationStream = (selector) => { 
    return DOM.fromMutationObserver(getElementsFromSelector(selector), {childList: true, subtree: true }); 
}
```

But this gives me the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: observableCreate is not defined
```

on the line:

```
call.dom.fromMutationObserver
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this issue was added after the version that's installed by npm, so adding the github url in package.json resolved the issue.